# No background option available in O365 Outlook Office 2016

Tags: microsoft-outlook, microsoft-office, office365, microsoft-office-2016

I am an O365 user and I have signed in using my O365 licensed email id to outlook and other Office programs.

Office365 version I use:

[image]

But I don't see the background option where you will be able change the background of title bar.

Please check the screenshot.

[image]

[image]

I have already set the following registry keys to 0

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\15.0\common\general - disablebackgrounds to 0
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office\16.0\common\general - disablebackgrounds to 0
```

And I still don't see the background option. How else to enable that option?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I resolved it by deleting the following registry key:

```
HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Policies\Microsoft\office
```

Then restart Office application.